# Need to fit the div with an image

Tags: html, css

I have to show an image in a div fully covered. Because if i need to resize the div image also need to be resizable. There for I need to fit the image width and height to my div entire size. I have tried but fail. Here is my code help me

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"><img src="hello.png" /></div>
</div>

.parent { 
        width: 150px; 
        height:150px; 
        position:fixed; 
        top:25px; 
        right:25px;
        border: solid 2px;
}
    .child{
        width: 150px;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: +5;
        top:25px;
    }

    .image-container img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post also the CSS script for the `.parent` and `.child` class?

Comment: Please who put -1 is please to release me. My Asking Question was blocked please do this favour for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve my issue my self by adding width on % of inner image

```css
  .parent { 
            width: 150px; 
            height:150px; 
            position:relative; 
            top:25px; 
            right:25px;
            border: solid 2px;
            float: right;
 }
        .child{
            float: left;
            position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: +5;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;

        }
        
        .child img{
            position: absolute;
            float: left;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"><img src="http://www.madaboutscience.com.au/store/images/genericTestTube.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead using `<img>`, I would use in `css`,like below. Try this method:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>  
</div>

.parent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    outline:1px dotted red;
}

.child{
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    background:   url("http://image URL")no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Note, when you ever post a question, please post what you tried and error you face  *above code does't make any sense*.

Comment: Sorry for the inclonvenience. Your code working well. My problem is if i reduce the parent size the child size also need to shrink on the aspect ratio.http://jsfiddle.net/h7bygb7z/